# WHERE-condition using information from array in a loop

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, where-clause, plpgsql

I would like to clean address data from the US. I want to impute state codes from a column (address) whenever the state code appears in the first two substrings (substring(address, 1, 2)). I built a foreach loop, looping through an array of US states. However, the condition `where = substring(address, 1, 2) = field` does not work.`field`is used in the loop: `foreach field in array arr loop`.

The whole code looks as follows:

```
create or replace function imp() RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare field varchar;
declare arr varchar[] := array['AL ', 'AK ', 'AZ ', 'AR ', 'CA ', 'CO ', 'CT ', 'DE ', 'DC ', 'FL ', 'GA ', 'HI ', 'ID ', 'IL ', 'IN ', 'IA ', 'KS ', 'KY ', 'LA ', 'ME ', 'MD ', 'MA ', 'MI ', 'MN ', 'MS ', 'MO ', 'MT ', 'NE ', 'NV ', 'NH ', 'NJ ', 'NM ', 'NY ', 'NC ', 'ND ', 'OH ', 'OK ', 'OR ', 'PA ', 'RI ', 'SC ', 'SD ', 'TN ', 'TX ', 'UT ', 'VT ', 'VA ', 'WA ',  'WV ',  'WI ', 'WY '];
begin
foreach field in array arr LOOP
update DE_inventor t1 set address_=t2.address_ from (
select
concat(address_, ' ', field)

as address_, pat_no, inventor
from DE_inventor
where ctry_code_inv = 'US' and substring(address, 1, 2)= field
) as t2
where t1.pat_no = t2.pat_no and t1.inventor = t2.inventor;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql'; 
select imp()
;
```

The loop works well in `concat(address_, ' ', field)` (tested and used in another procedure as well), but not in the where condition.
Does anyone have an idea why and what could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the extra space in your array elements:

```
declare arr varchar[] := array['AL ', 'AK ', 'AZ ',
                                  ^      ^      ^ those
```

Are preventing this from ever being true:

```
substring(address, 1, 2)= field
```

substring (x, 1, 2) will always be two characters and will never match a three character field, which the array elements are.

So first off, can you strip those extra spaces out and try?

```
create or replace function imp() RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
  field varchar;
  arr varchar[] := array['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', ... 'WY'];
begin
```

Secondly -- can you load the states into a table instead and use that instead of an array?  Depending on what you do, it will likely come in handy more than once.

Third, if `inventor` and `pat_no` are the primary key for your table, then I think a single update statement might work better than a function/loop:

```
update de_inventor
set address_ = address_ || ' ' || left (address, 1, 2)
where
  ctry_code_inv = 'US' and
  left (address, 2) in ('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR' .. 'WY')
```

If those aren't the primary key, then there may be unintended consequences with your update statement, but I don't know that for sure.

It's food for thought either way.

Comment: excellent answer. Thank you. Yes, indeed, I did not pay attention to the extra space, sorry, but I now use the 2nd approach. Any advantage of using "left" instead of "substring"?

Comment: The only possible advantage of `left` over `substring` is less code and maybe better transparency to the reader that you are taking the left two characters.  `substring` is pretty mainstream, so anyone familiar with SQL or computing in general *should* know what that means, and one might argue that it's more standard than is `left`.  By the way, when I said `left (address, 1, 2)` that should be `left (address, 2)`.  I'm glad this was helpful.  Yes, whenever you can do a single SQL transaction over a loop, you want to.  Loops are widely used when not needed, so don't feel bad.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need loops nor plpgsql code for this update as the simple SQL statement does the job:

```
update de_inventor
set address_ = concat(address_, ' ', substring(address, 1, 2))
where ctry_code_inv = 'US' 
and substring(address, 1, 2) in ('AL', 'AK', 'WY'); -- list of all state codes here
```

In cases like this one an SQL approach is more efficient and simpler than loops in functions.

Comment: excellent advice. Yes, I missed the most obvious thing to do because I was totally focused on using loops.